What tools should I use if my exe file is corrupted?
I used the Tiny C Compiler and now I have an exe file with Exec format error.
compiler
//good
int ba[499119036];

int main(int argc, char **argv) {return 0;}

//bad
int ba[499119037];

int main(int argc, char **argv) {return 0;}

I tried to find something in the diff, but so far without success. What tools should be used to find the corrupt part?
